# What makes ice shatter in icecube tray?

Tags: freezing

I have two identical ice cube trays. When I twist the trays to remove ice, sometimes the whole cubes pop out perfectly, but sometimes they shatter and I get lots of shards with bits of ice stuck to the bottoms of the molds.

What can I do to consistently get the whole cubes out?

Comment: Buy a flexible icecube mold. Problem solved.

Comment: @rumtscho: I have yet to find a flexible mold with a half-decent cover/lid. I personally almost always use the OXO trays, and although I haven't had a lot of problems with shattering, it's still useful to know how to eject the plastic trays. I think the shape may matter more than the flexibility; it's when the cubes freeze together that you usually run into trouble.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

what i used to do for popping whole cubes is-take out the ice tray from freezer. Put it under running tap of normal temp water(for 2-4 secs) from both sides of ice tray,from top and bottom back of ice tray. then twist the trays to remove ice. It pops out shattered ice less frequently.